# How to share text with AirDrop?

Tags: macos, monterey, airdrop

I'm trying to airdrop a password from one MacBook to another one.

I highlighted the text in textedit, right-clicked it, hovered share, but AirDrop does not appear as it normally always would.

How can I conveniently share long strings with a nearby MacBook?

Comment: How about the shared clipboard?

Comment: @allan it's not the same Apple account on both devices, is it still possible?

Comment: In that case, no.   You”ll have to send a file - a simple txt file will work - if using AirDrop

Comment: Or, you can paste into a Note and share the note.